# Specify Constant Instead of Variable to Unwanted Parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, return-value, function-call

Let's say you are using a pre-defined function that has return parameters that are not needed. To clarify, either the function doesn't need the value or you don't need the result or both.

Is there any drawback or problem with using a constant in the call? Or is it better to create a temporary variable just for the purposes of filling out the call?

The goal is to reduce variable definitions in the calling program. The subroutine definition cannot be changed. The question is whether supplying a constant is advisable/recommended in this case.

```vb
Dim res As Double = 2.0#
''' do not need second/third results, third value isn't used
''' calling the function this way saves creating two extra variables
Call AddOneTwoThree(res, 3.0#, 0.0#)

''' this function cannot be changed
Public Sub AddOneTwoThree(ByRef first As Double, ByRef second As Double, ByRef third As Double)
    first = first + second
    second = second + third
    third = third
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code work?  What kind of drawback are you looking for?  Methods like that are typically harder to debug since it's returning a bunch of things instead of a function that returns "one" thing.

Comment: yes, the code works, in some cases the other results are needed so the function definition can't change, the goal is to simplify the calling code by not defining variables that will not be used in that instance.

Comment: I am supplying a constant that the function is trying to modify so I'm wondering if that creates a problem at run-time with garbage collection or messes up the internal workings of VB.Net in a way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It obviously won't change a constant.

Comment: Consider making them `Optional` parameters. i.e. `AddOneTwoThree(ByRef first As Double, Optional ByRef second As Double=0.0, Optional ByRef third As Double=0.0)` as it will simplify the calling code even further.

Comment: I don't see any functions returning anything. I don't see and Const keyword.

Comment: The basis of the question is that the function definition can't change. I'm specifically only looking for permissible/recommended options for the calling program. With Option Strict On, I don't get an error when specifiying 0.0# for a ByRef Double parameter so I'm assuming it is okay and better than creating a variable that is never used.

Comment: The reason you do not get an error is because the your usage syntax is valid. If you are questioning why it is valid, that question can only be answered by those that designed the language. If you use a decompiler like ILSpy, you will see that the compiler supplies variable declarations/assignments for the _constant_ values that you pass as to the function.

Comment: You're passing literals, not constants.  Just use `Nothing` as the argument for a `ByRef` parameter if you don't care about the output.

Comment: With regards to my previous comment, I do this regularly when calling `TryParse` methods if I want to validate but don't care about the converted result.

Comment: By the way, the `Call` keyword is pointless in your code.  The only use I've ever found for the `Call` keyword is when you want to invoke a constructor without assigning the new object to anything.  You're not allowed to start a line with the `New` keyword, so using the `Call` keyword makes this possible.  It's rare that you should want to do such a thing though, so you can pretty much forget about `Call`. It was required in certain circumstances in VB6 so it still exists in VB.NET so that upgraded code works as is. It doesn't serve a useful purpose though.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the comments provided by [tntinmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) and [jmcilhinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney) are good answers from my perspective.

`0.0#` or `Nothing` can be specified for a `ByRef` `Double` parameter if the result is not needed assuming values of `0.0#` does not adversely affect the output.

I tested with `Nothing` and the result is the same as if `0.0#` was specified.